# Kerberos no longer working after running application pool as a gMSA with SPN registered for domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, kerberos

I have an application that is configured for Windows Authentication in IIS and was previously distributing Kerberos tickets when running as a local application pool identity.

Because I may want to run the application on multiple servers behind an Amazon ELB, I did the following:

- Registered a group managed service account
- `aspnet_regiis -GA`
- Modified the application pool to run as that group managed service account
- Added SPNs for the FQDN, ie `http/mysite.mydomain.test` and `https/mysite.mydomain.test`, and verified they are present

However, when I try to authenticate now, I only get `Authorization: NTLM` in the response rather than `Authorization: Negotiate`...

My question is: how can I go about debugging why this is happening, ie why IIS is no longer sending back Kerberos tickets?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the SPN to the group Managed Service account?

Check for duplicate SPN?  (setspn -x)

Go to the providers for Windows Authentication on your site and move Negotiate above NTLM, or just remove NTLM.  Either it will work or you'll get an error that will help you track it down.

[image]

Comment: The question specifically relates to gMSAs though. I could get it to work with a regular service account but not a gMSA

Comment: Are you using impersonation or delegation?  If so, that is more restrictive with gMSA and you must use constrained delegation for it to work.

Comment: This might help get you pointed in the right direction, if you haven't solved the problem already.

https://pisquare.osisoft.com/thread/14246-gmsa-impersonation-to-pi-af